# Fit Polynomial between two tangents python

Tags: python, curve-fitting

I want to fit a polynomial between two lines each one with its respective slope, see figure below.[image]

Let's say I have {L_1, m_1} and {L_0, m_0} where {L_i} is the line and {m_i} the slope of the respective line. There may be other parameters required to fit the polynomial but the initial constraint I have are the distance between lines that are parallel to each other and the slopes. Does anyone know a library helpful for this task? thanks.

Comment: Please repeat [on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) from the
[intro tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).  
"Show me how to solve this coding problem?" is off-topic for Stack Overflow.
You have to make an honest attempt at the solution, and then ask a *specific* question about your implementation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The NumPy library provides a good tool for this problem, see [numpy.polyfit](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.polyfit.html). Below a source code of how to implement the polyfit function. **Note** that at least 2 pairs of points are required, 2 at the end and 2 at the beginning of the. function. These pairs of points should have the slope of the line. Then from the final points, the tangent can be extended. This approach is pragmatic but it works for what was needing

```
import warnings
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 



def polynomial_fit(x1,y1, x2, y2, x3, y3, x4, y4, x5, y5, x6, y6):
    '''
    coordinates required for polynomial generation, -pairs at the begining 
    3 pairs at the  end
    xi, east
    yi, west
    return 
    Polynomial coefficient of degree 3
    '''

    # x coordinates of the required six points for x and y
    x_n = np.array([x1, x2, x3,  x4, x5, x6])
    y_n = np.array([y1, y2, y3, y4, y5, y6])
    
    # polyfit function
    poly = np.polyfit(x_n, y_n, 3)
    
    # writes the coeffiecient with respective x^deg
    eq_poly = np.poly1d(poly)
    
    
    print(eq_poly)
    # set range where x will be plotted
    t = np.linspace(x1, x6, 100)
    
    # creates a plot with the six points polynomial
    plt.scatter(x_n, y_n)
    plt.plot(x_n, y_n, "--", t, eq_poly(t), "-")
    
    
    
test = polynomial_fit(7.19447831, 369605.543, 
                      9, 369613.4986, 
                      10, 369624.701, 
                      42, 369851.94471859,
                      43, 369865.3556,
                      44, 369878.7666)
```

The fit can be seen below. I think the docstring explains really well so it will benefit anyone with the same problem.
[image]